# Target specific google chart data set

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Say if my google chart data array looks like below,
Is there a way to target specific data set for google charts and do something.
something like if data = "13 dec 11 Tue" then the point of 56 should use a different color from rest...

```
["13 Dec 11 Tue",56],
["14 Dec 11 Wed",168],
["15 Dec 11 Thu",181],
["16 Dec 11 Fri",163],
["17 Dec 11 Sat",172]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but it requires coding in javascript and cannot be done innately within Google Visualization save within tables using a [ColorFormatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#colorformatter). Assuming you want to do it in a chart, you need to write code to do it.

## Option 1: Create an Array of Colors

You can use the [`series` configuration option of most charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options) to set the color of how each series is displayed.

For instance, if I have 3 series, then I can set the following option to turn the second one red:

```
series: [{}, {color: 'red'}, {}]
```

This will set no options for series 1 and 3, but change the color of series 2 to red.

So you can loop through your data with Javascript, and create an array of colors to assign to the various series. For instance, if you want any value in column 1 higher than 10 to be red, you could do it as follows:

```
var colorArray = {};
for(i=0;i<data.getNumberOfRows;i++) {
  if(data.getDataValue(i, 1)>10)
    colorArray.push({color: 'red'});
  else
    colorArray.push({});
};
```

Then you set the options as:

```
options = {series = colorArray};
```

*Note: The above code has not been checked, it probably has errors since I just typed it out. If it doesn't work, correct my code, but the logic is appropriate.*

## Option 2: Move the Series

By default, each different column of data will have a different color. You can create a similar loop that checks the value of each item, and moves it to another series. Just create a different for loop that goes through the values you want to check, and if it finds what you're looking for, move the value in to that new series.

This is more complex, but it will give you more flexibility depending on what you want to do (since you have an entirely different series, you can customize it with different line size, or markers, or bar width, or whatever).

Whatever you pick to do, the best thing is to play with it and find something you like and that's easiest for you to code with your data.

Comment: Can we do the same for line charts which contains multiple lines ?

Comment: @RapunzelEugene yes you can.